# IE11でvideoタグの映像を保存するJavaScriptが知りたいです

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, webrtc

IE11で動作するWEBアプリケーションを作成しています。

WebRTCを利用し、videoタグにデバイスのカメラの映像を表示させ、撮影ボタンをクリックすることで、そのタイミングのvideoタグの映像を画像としてローカルに保存することができました。

しかし今回、追加機能として画像ではなく、動画をローカルに保存したいのですが、難航しております。
Chromeではvideoタグの映像をMediaRecorderAPIを利用し、保存することができたのですが、IE11ではサポートしていないようです。

どなたか知恵をお貸しいただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/151963

Answer (score 1):

JavaScriptではありませんが、プログラムで何とかできるかもしれない方法として。

廃止予定で、今も制限が掛かっているプラグインですが、IE11にこだわるならFlashPlayerとかRealPlayerなどを使う方法が考えられます。

こんなQ&Aがあります。
[動画ファイルの保存](https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/8560488.html)

> Real Playerはすでにインストール済とのこと。
>
> ＞＞何か設定することがあるのですか？
>
> ＩＥを立ち上げる → ツール → インターネットオプション → 詳細設定 →
>   「セキュリティ」の中の「拡張保護モードで64ビットプロセッサを有効にする」のチェックを外す →
>   同じく「セキュリティ」の中の「拡張保護モードを有効にする」のチェックを外す。
>
> これで、Flash Playerで再生される動画で 「このビデオをダウンロード」
>   というアイコンが「動画再生中」に動画画面の右上部にスーと出たり引っ込んだりしますので、そのアイコンをクリックすれば、ダウンロードができます。
>
> ただし、100％ではありません。 そうですねぇ 98％位はできます。
>
> しかし、ここでダウロードした動画は Peal Player でだけしか再生できませんので、もし、例えば Windows Media
>   Player などで再生したい場合は、無料のコンバータを導入して「Flv}形式から「Mpeg4」などに変換する必要があります。
>
> もしコンバータ（無料）をお望みなら、再度「補足」ででもご連絡ください。

また音関係でこんな記事があります。APIの中には動画が使えるものもあるのでは？
[ブラウザにおける録音及び音声ファイルの生成、転送](https://tech.at-iroha.jp/?p=663)

> Internet Explorer 11 における録音 Internet Explorer 11 では Web Audio API
>   がサポートされていないため、Flash Player を使用する必要があります。 Flash Player には Microphone
>   という録音を行うクラスが標準で用意されております。

さらに、プラグイン同様に外されつつある技術ですがActiveXコントロールというのもあります。
IE11をサポートしているか不明ですが、機能説明にActiveX componentsとあったので。
[BB FlashBack SDK](http://www.bbflashback-japan.jp/bbflashbacksdk.aspx)